# MVC - dbcontext database connection string

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, model-view-controller

i've created a MVC project and the database was created through dbcontext on localdb... later i changed my database location and i added this string connection pointing to the place that i pasted the database copy. My problem is that instead of using the database, MVC created a new one with the same name on same location, what am i doing wrong? 
see here [my connection string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0KMn.png) , [my class context and solution explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7542e.png) and [visual studio SSOE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TM5K0.png) ...

PS: i have not installed sql server, im using visual studio SSOE.

Thanks you...

Answer (score 0):

Try explicitly telling EF what connection string to use by adding a constructor and passing it in:

```
public class cl_Context: DbContext
{
    public cl_Context()
        : base("cl_Context")
    {
    }
}
```